# weird behavior in tableview iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

This is kind of weird. I have a table view in my app which is showing fetched data from the database. If i scroll down and select a cell the text would change and a line of text from some previous cell will be placed above the current selected cell's text. I know this might be due to the reuseIdentifier, but i have no idea how to fix that. Here's the code i'm using:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UILabel* labelCourse;
    UILabel* labelPlace;

    static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }

    Course *course = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        course = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        course = [self.courses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }    


    CGRect labelCourseFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 25);
    labelCourse = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelCourseFrame];
    labelCourse.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    labelCourse.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelCourse];

    CGRect labelPlaceFrame = CGRectMake(10, 35, 290, 25);
    labelPlace = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelPlaceFrame];
    labelPlace.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    labelPlace.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelPlace];

    labelCourse.text = course.name;
    labelPlace.text = course.location;

    [labelCourse release];        
    [labelPlace release];
//    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@""];

    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the creation part to inside the `if` clause that creates a new cell.

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    CGRect labelCourseFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 25);
    labelCourse = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelCourseFrame];
    labelCourse.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    labelCourse.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelCourse];

    CGRect labelPlaceFrame = CGRectMake(10, 35, 290, 25);
    labelPlace = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelPlaceFrame];
    labelPlace.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    labelPlace.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelPlace];

    labelCourse.tag = 50;
    labelPlace.text = 51;

    [labelCourse release];        
    [labelPlace release];
}
```

As you see I've attached `tag`s to the views so that I can retrieve the labels when the cells are being reused. Now get the labels,

```
UILabel * labelCourse = [cell viewWithTag:50];
UILabel * labelPlace = [cell viewWithTag:51];
```

and set them,

```
labelCourse.text = course.name;
labelPlace.text = course.location;
```

Comment: So in conclusion, the tags did the trick? Thanks, it's working now. You've saved my day.

Comment: Yes, for this case. You can also think of creating a custom cell so that you can directly use the properties (assuming labels are declared as properties in the custom cell) rather than having to use the tags.

Comment: This is actually not working as i expected. The cells are showing the wrong values. I don't know if it's because i'm reusing these tags. I get the same value like 5 times meaning that old values are replacing the new ones. What could be the cause?

Comment: @Ernesto Just to confirm, is your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method same as in [`this pastie`](http://pastie.org/2137294).

Comment: i didn't have it like that, i used your pastie and it's working, for now. I was setting the text inside the `if(cell == nil)` i guess that was the problem. Now in the ``UILabel * labelCourse = [cell viewWithTag:50]; i get a warning `Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UILabel *' with an expression of type 'UIView *' Thanks for the help.
`

Comment: You can cast it. `UILabel * labelCourse = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:50];`